# ASP.NET users online state store

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a small internal web system designed in `ASP.NET MVC 5. Max 50 users.

I am trying to implement something along the lines of this:

[image]

The idea is to display who is currently online (logged in on the website) to all the other users.

How would I go about implementing this in `.net`.

I have two issues:

1. Knowing / Managing the users login status
2. The transport mechanism / technology

For issue 1, I have looked into the `SessionData` property in `.net`  i'm just not 100% sure on which mechanism within the MVC framework to use.

Could I use some sort of session linked variable?

For issue 2, do I need to have a `JavaScript` Function fire off every 30 seconds to say, "hey i'm still here" and  then store that in memory or db and query it every 30 seconds.

Comment: you can use SignalR

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp-net/tracking-online-users-with-signalr/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's very easy by using [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr):

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes
>   developing real-time web functionality easy. SignalR allows
>   bi-directional communication between server and client. Servers can
>   now push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes
>   available. SignalR supports Web Sockets, and falls back to other
>   compatible techniques for older browsers. SignalR includes APIs for
>   connection management (for instance, connect and disconnect events),
>   grouping connections, and authorization.

I did it myself, you can look at my site [SignalRTC](https://signalrtc.com) to check how it works.

Comment: Ok, Cool I will look into signal R as the means of communication. Now more importantly, how do I track users Login status?

Comment: there are events: onConnected, onDisconnected